A modern reinterpretation of Vandermonde's mathematical achievements
I already posted a question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange about a related topic, but after posting it, I realized that it is more appropriate for this site, so I am posting it again in this site.
I became interested in Vandermonde, a mathematician who was involved in the beginning development of the concept of determinant. However, if you read the book Unknown Quantity: A Real and Imaginary History of Algebra pp.117-121, you will find that Vandermonde studied quadratic equation, cubic equation, and quartic equation, which can be the starting point of Galois theory.
If you read pp.11-12 of A case of mathematical eponymy: the Vandermonde determinant, you will see that Vandermonde's work on equations led to the birth of determinants. And if you read page 81 of this book A history of abstract algebra
, you will see the following passage:

Subsequent problems that
gave rise to new uses of determinants included elimination theory (finding conditions
under which two polynomials have a common root), transformation of coordinates
to simplify algebraic expressions (e.g., quadratic forms), change of variables in multiple integrals, solution of systems of differential equations, and celestial mechanics.

I think Vandermonde's research on determinants corresponds to the following two of the above quotes:


elimination theory (finding conditions under which two polynomials have a common root)

transformation of coordinates to simplify algebraic expressions (e.g., quadratic forms)



And I also searched Vandermonde's original paper
Mémoire sur l'Élimination, M. Vandermonde, Histoire de L'Academie Royale des Sciences, 1772, part twopp.526-532 because I wanted to know the original author's thoughts. If the formula is blurry, also see The theory of Determinants in the historical order of development pp.17-24.
Ultimately, what I want to ask is whether my thought process that the study of Vandermonde's equations led to the study of determinants and that these two are related to elimination theory and transformation of coordinates to simplify algebraic expressions is correct, and if so, I would like to see an explanation of why these two are related using modern mathematical methods.

Lebesgue surveyed Vandermonde's mathematical works in L'oeuvre mathématique de Vandermonde. Perhaps it has what you are looking for.

@Conifold Hello, thank you so much for your comment. However, this language is French, and I am not fluent in French, so I used Google Translate, but the language is translated awkwardly. If you don't mind, could you please highlight the important parts that answer my question?
